# How to inject blank rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]Please see my image. I have a spreadsheet about 2200 rows long. I need to inject/add extra 5 blank rows in between each purple border which goes all the way down as per the picture. Any easy way of doing this?[![enter image description here. So currently there are 5 blank (ignore the numbers in the white cells), but this needs to be increase to 10 blank cells for each section.][2]][2]

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: You don't say top, bottom or middle of the purple rows but you also didn't show any effort.

Comment: So currently there are 5 blank rows, but this needs to be increase to 10 blank cells for each section.

Comment: But...it's _not_ blank. Or am I imagining those numbers XD But I guess your point is it doesn't matter where they are inserted. _Still_ didn't try anything XD

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot. Imagine the white rows are all blank. Ignore the numbers. The purple rows are correct.

Comment: Really? 23 hours later and you _still_ haven't tried anything??

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter on top of the column, filter rows by color (only white), delete values and then switch the filter off.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the image. I just need to add an extra 5 blank rows in between each purple section now.